# Upload documents to an external fileshare using SP 2007

Tags: 2007, file-upload

Due to storage limitations within our portal environment, a user's request to have a sp 2007 list that could potential grow to 100 gbs with our documents is not possible to implement.

Therefore, I'm looking for a solution where the user can attach documents to a SP list form and those documents would be uploaded to a external fileshare on the same domain as our portal servers. Verses the sharepoint content db houses the sp site collection.

I'm wondering if this is easy to do within an infopath form by directing the attach file control to a udcx file but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [Nintex Workflow](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/Workflow2007.aspx) then you can use one of their built in actions to move files to your local file system.

You can also use the free [DocAve Extender](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/ebs-external-blob-storage-in-sharepoint-2007). More RBS info can be found [in this related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/ebs-external-blob-storage-in-sharepoint-2007) ([and this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10298/remote-storeage-rbs-or-external-add-on)).

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [EBS/RBS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx) or a thrid party like [StoragePoint](http://www.storagepoint.com/) to offload the files/blobs to fileshares.

Comment: thanks but i forgot to mention that this is sharepoint 2007 environment. i'd like to avoid third party tools if possible.

Comment: EBS is available in 2007.  The complexities of blob offloading warrant the cost of third party tools in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from EBS, the only other supportable option you have would be to write a custom IRouter for a Records Center (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.irouter(v=office.12).aspx). You'd effectively write the BLOB out inside of the IRouter and replace it with a stub pointing to the external BLOB.

The IRouter is much less functional and transparent than EBS, but far easier to build than an EBS provider.  I would recommend EBS because once implemented it is completely transparent to the end user and not limited to a Record Center.  I would also recommend purchasing a solution from a 3rd party rather than rolling your own...lots of gotchas with EBS that aren't covered in the Msft doc on the interface and/or blog posts I've seen on the technology.

Comment: Rob is one of the authorities in this arena.  If he's saying get a third party tool to handle it, that carries a lot of weight.