# ftp upload in sharepoint and presenting list of files on ftp server in sharepoint page

Tags: 2007, development

I have SharePoint 2007 portal  and I need a solution for my problem the problem is as describe below

I need a page (in SharePoint portal) that it could be send some files to a ftp folder in a ftp server somewhere else. And this page shows the files related to exact user (with particular permission for this user only and I have many users in for example my domain and active directory) that these files are in ftp server I told before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question on stackoverflow:
[Upload files to Sharepoint document libraries via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450915/upload-files-to-sharepoint-document-libraries-via-ftp)

Seems like there is not OOB functionality for this, but ofcourse can be achieved via coding... But I wonder why are you using FTP at all, why not SharePoint Document Libraries to save documents, if the document sizes are the problem then you can use **Remote BLOB Storage**
See These:
[EBS (External Blob Storage) in SharePoint 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/ebs-external-blob-storage-in-sharepoint-2007)
[External BLOB Storage (EBS) for SharePoint 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2009/05/16/external-blob-storage-ebs-for-sharepoint-2007.aspx)

If you insist on FTP, then [FTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) is your friend... and you can see how to [List Directory details from FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx) and [Download files from FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx)

But you need to make connection to FTP Server each time the user visits the page you are showing documents from FTP on, to overcome that you can either write a TimerJob which timely syncs the FTP with Document Library [overhead, you will be keeping copy of documents at two places] and make the TimerJob to run in off hours, and show the documents from document library!

I wonder, how you are saving permissions in FTP? Please let me know if you need more help!